# MySQL: how to ignore that column is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have a mysql query like this:

```
SELECT * from T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.t1_id = T1.id 
INNER JOIN T3 ON T3.t1_id = T1.id 
where T3.my_column = my_column
```

I get the `Column 'my_column' in where clause is ambiguous` error, because all the 3 tables has the `my_column` column.

What I can NOT do now is to say `where T3.my_column = T1.my_column`, because I'm using an ORM in which it is impossible now, because I have to setup the condition in the *association definition* where I do not know if there would be a `T1` or `T2` table.

The actual value of `my_column` will be the same in `T1` and `T2`, which means my condition would be ok for both `T1.my_column` and `T2.my_column`.

Is there any way in `MySQL` to say *do not care about ambiguous columns, just take one of them randomly* ?

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
SELECT * from T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.t1_id = T1.id 
INNER JOIN T3 ON T3.t1_id = T1.id 
where T3.my_column = IGNORE_AMBIGUITY(my_column)
```

***The actual problem***

I'm defining an `n:m` relationship in `sequelize`, which is an `ORM` for `node.js`.

All my tables have an `id` and a `company_id`, the `id` is not unique, only the `id-company_id` pairs are unique.

This is how I define the association:

```
{
    through: {
        model: 'T1_to_T2',
        scope: {
            company_id: {$col: 'company_id'}, // Problematic part
        }
    },
    foreignKey: 'T2_id'
}
```

My problem is that through the `T1_to_T2` relationship table, for `company_id=X1`, I'll get the relations of `X2` or `X3` companies because the query doesn't care about the `company_id` field in the relationship table.

Comment: right. it's `where`

Comment: When you have such a weird problem you have to ask yourself what you are doing wrong instead of how to make the software do it your way.

Comment: thanks for the comment @juergend, I've updated the question with my actual problem.

Comment: Can't you simply define a two-column Primary/Foreign Key?

Comment: That's what `sequelize` doesn't support yet :(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know if it would be in T2 or T3, you have a problem.  What is your expected behavior?  If you are trying to join one or the other then how do you know what you are filtering?

I think you need to rethink your problem first and define what you want from your query before deciding how to solve it.  You get the error because MySQL cannot determine what you want.

If you really want one arbitrarily, instead do:

```
 WHERE t3.mycolumn = t1.column OR t3.mycolumn = t2.mycolumn limit 1
```

That is not random but it is arbitrary.

Comment: the problem is I still do not know if there will be a `T2` or `T1` table. It could happen, there will only be `Tx` and `Ty`

Comment: If that is the case your joins are a problem too.  Again define clearly what you want out and then look at the math to get it.

Comment: One more thought.  If your issue is that the ORM needs to set this up as a relational bit, put the condition dynamically in the JOIN based on what is defined in the ORM.

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution, but in that case I'd have to set it in every JOIN query. It would be cleaner to do it only once, in the association def.

Comment: Don't you have the same problem with joins then?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT * from T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.t1_id = T1.id 
INNER JOIN T3 ON T3.t1_id = T1.id 
where T3.my_column = (select my_column from T1)
```